# How to leverage ServiceStack Session/Cache in ASP.NET 4 Web forms website?

Tags: asp.net, servicestack

Having read bits and pieces of source code on github [ISession](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/CacheAccess/ISession.cs) and [SessionFactory](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/SessionFactory.cs) and a bunch of other files (they are gems of coding goodness) I'd like to be able to pull the session component into a legacy VB.Net ASP.NET Web forms website, and have it wrap my existing ServiceStack Caching (implemented Memcached). Is there a NuGet package that I can use?, sort of like MVC [MVC PowerPack](http://www.servicestack.net/mvc-powerpack/).

**Update**

After a bit more digging, I have found [Starter ASP.NET](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack.Host.AspNet) which may have the features I need, but I reluctant to install that into our dev main line at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [MVC Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Mvc-integration) and [ServiceStack Integration](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/ServiceStack-Integration) docs which show how you can use the `ServiceStackController` in the `ServiceStack.Mvc` package to access ServiceStack dependencies.